# using proxy with native windows 10 apps twitter and facebook

Tags: windows-10, vpn, proxy, windows-store-app

I live in a very very good country that twitter and facebook and many more websites has been banned by government , by the way I want to use native apps from windows 10 (store apps) of those social networks .

When I use other proxy softwares like Cisco AnyConnect or Kerio VPN Client I can by pass barriers but for some reasons I have not access to accounts for those clients and I want to use public softwares like FreeGate or Psiphon. 
But when I open apps after launching freegate or psiphon they can not bypass banned restrictions for twitter and facebook apps in windows 10, I used Group Policy Edit for Internet apps and

```
netsh
winhttp
import proxy source=ie
```

but had no luck ! 
can anyone please help me with this ! ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for VPN recommendations? Your question would be better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. That being said, you should try out [CyberGhost VPN](https://www.cyberghostvpn.com/en_us) or [VPN Gate](http://www.vpngate.net/en/about_overview.aspx)

Comment: No I know how to find VPN Recommandations and apps , my problem is that native windows 10 apps don't work with common proxy apps but work with any connect and kerio client , My browser can by pass with freegate and psiphon but native apps can not !

Comment: Cisco AnyConnect and Kerio VPN client are both VPN clients. Could you try either of the VPN software I mentioned in my earlier comment and see if it works for you?

Comment: The VPN Gate app solved my problem temporarily , I appreciate the help very very much , but this is not real answer to my first question , the question was "Can I configure native windows 10 apps like twitter and facebook to use proxy servers , they work with vpn and vpn clients already !?" the answer can be "No , the windows 10 native apps aren't configurable on proxies" Or "Yes , you can config ... to force windows 10 native apps to work with proxy servers! " thank you again !

Comment: Does the registry edit method [mentioned here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/setup-proxy-metro-application-windows-8) work? You'll need the address of an HTTP proxy.

Comment: I Checked the registry method that you've linked and It doesn't work !